# Задача на объекты в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Короче говоря, я новичок в JS и вот решал задачу. Смысл задачи: если значение объекта является числом (number), то его значение надо увеличить вдвое. Вот рабочий код:

```
let menu = {
    width: 200, 
    height: 300,
    title: "my menu"
};

function multiplyNumeric (obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "number") {
            obj[key] *= 2;
        }
    }
}

multiplyNumeric(menu);
```

Возможно, мой вопрос глупый, но почему этот же код не работает через точечную нотацию? Я имею ввиду вот так:

```
let menu = {
    width: 200, 
    height: 300,
    title: "my menu"
};

function multiplyNumeric (obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj.key === "number") {
            obj.key *= 2;
        }
    }
}

multiplyNumeric(menu);
```

Comment: Потому что вы путаете значение переменной и ключ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что у объекта нет свойства, которое называется `key`.

Название свойства, к которому Вы пытаетесь обратиться через точку `obj.key`, не имеет никакого отношения к локальной переменной `key`.

```js
let menu = {
    width: 200, 
    height: 300,
    title: "my menu"
};

let key = 'title';
console.log(menu.width);
console.log(menu.key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Существует и другой способ обратиться к элементу объекта - используя обращение не через квадратные скобки, а через точку: не `obj['key']`, а `obj.key`.
В этом случае, что мы обращаемся к свойству объекта.
При таком способе обращения на названия свойств (то есть ключей) накладываются ограничения: они не должны начинаться с цифры, не должны иметь символ дефиса или символ пробела внутри.

Если у вас есть такой ключ - используйте обращение через квадратные скобки.